# setText() method for edit text in adapter from another class

Tags: java, android, listview

i've this adapter

```
    @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
            if(view == null) {
                holder = new Holder();
                inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout_adapter, null);
                holder.textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
                holder.editText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
                view.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (Holder)view.getTag();
            }

            holder.editText.setText(myStringVariable);
            holder.editText.setId(position);
            holder.editText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }           
            });
            holder.textView.setText(textVar);



return view;
    }
```

now my question is: if i want to setText from (for example) the edit text with id 3 from another class, is possible?

Comment: could you please clarify your need with a concrete example ?

Comment: What do you mean by another class ? the position in getView method is not always the one you are expecting, due to recycling concept. So the position won't suit with what you want to achieve ! Tell us what you want to do exactly !

Comment: if for example from another class i want to set the text at the second item (edt text) of the adapter how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite unsure what you want, but you could make `EditText` a global variable and access it that way.

Answer (score -1):

If you can get the object of Edit_Text in the 3rd class, u could make effect on the variables u required.....Please tell us where you are getting errors

Comment: this is not an answer, should be a comment !!